# adyen payment mount is not working inside reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, adyen

The following code is not rendering the html. I guess .mount is not re-render the html in the test-container class.

```
componentDidMount() {
     const originKey = getOriginKey(this.props.subscriptionInfo);
     const checkout = new window.AdyenCheckout({
     locale: 'en-US',
     originKey,
     loadingContext: 'https://checkoutshopper 
  test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/',
  onChange: function() {},
  onError: console.error
});

console.log(checkout);

window.securedFields = checkout
  .create('securedfields', {
  type: 'card',
  groupTypes: ['mc', 'visa', 'amex', 'bcmc', 'maestro'],
  allowedDOMAccess: false, // Whether encrypted blobs will be added to the DOM. OPTIONAL - defaults to false
  autoFocus: true,
  onFieldValid,
  onConfigSuccess,
  onAllValid,
  onError
})
.mount('.test-container');
}
```

Comment: Hi @kulls,
Could you add more information about this? Is there any error in the console? What's inside the ".test-container" HTML? Do you have a form like the one in the step 2 of [this page](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/cards/custom-card-fields#collect-shopper-details-with-secured-fields)?
Do you see a spinner or nothing at all?
Also, are you sure the originKey was retrieved when creating the instance of `AdyenCheckout`? Another thing to try could be to use a reference instead of a selector when mounting the Secured Fields.
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The `.mount` method appends iframes to existing form fields. In case of the secured field component, it mounts iframes to  elements inside the Node that you pass to the `.mount` method (it uses `document.querySelector` internally).

This is more or less the structure from [docs](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/cards/custom-card-fields).

From my experience, it works on any  element with correct `data-cse` attribute. Just put those elements in your render fn and mount Adyen checkout.